# Calling State from another method in the class

Tags: reactjs

Currently trying to call state in constructors from another method but I keep getting null despite being able to call it in render(). In render {this.state.email} works perfectly. Any thoughts on this?

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
     email: props.email
  };
}
emailGetClick(event) {
  console.log(event);
  console.log(this.state.email);
}
```

Comment: how do you call `emailGetClick`? Could you post code where do you use `emailGetClick`?

Comment: <a onClick={this.emailGetClick} className="formButton" href="#">Text</a>

Comment: `<a onClick={this.emailGetClick.bind(this)} className="formButton" href="#">Text</a>` - you need set `this` for `emailGetClick`

Comment: ah, i didn't realize onclick methods had to be bound. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to bind your method in the constructor function.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
     email: props.email
  };
  this.emailGetClick = this.emailGetClick.bind(this) // bind method
}
emailGetClick(event) {
  console.log(event);
  console.log(this.state.email);
}
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/221/). 
I hope it will  help you

Thanks